# Elasticsearch Rest Client Update Operation

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am working on a project which uses Elasticsearch 5.4 as a datastore. I need to update a field in all the documents in a index. We are using Java RestClient for connection between Java and Elasticsearch and i am not able to find any documentation or Resources for Update API in RestClient 5.4.3.

Can someone please guide me how to proceed from here!

Note : I cannot use Transport client.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Elastic's Rest client or some HTTP REST client ?

Comment: @aclokay I am using Elastic's Rest Client.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did you try to perform POST request on `_update_by_query` endpoint?

Please take a look on [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docs-update-by-query.html):

> The simplest usage of `_update_by_query` just performs an update on every document in the index without changing the source.

and

> So far we’ve only been updating documents without changing their source. That is genuinely useful for things like picking up new properties but it’s only half the fun. `_update_by_query` supports a script object to update the document.